# Is Microsoft package Mono.Posix.NetStandard supported on .Net Core 3.1 in Linux?

Tags: .net-core, mono, posix

I'm building a .NetCore 3.1 console application to run in the Linux OS.
I'm attempting to use the Mono.Posix libraries.

If I use Mono.Posix-4.5 (May 2015), the app builds both under on Linux and Windows 10 platforms.

If I attempt to use Mono.Posix.NetStandard, the app builds in my Windows 10 environment.
However, it does not build on Linux.
I get the following error message:
[image: Error messages when attempting to build in Rider on Linux Ubuntu 20.04]

I want to use the latest stable version of Mono.

Is .NetStandard supported with .NetCore 3.1?

Is there something I missing here in terms of requiting additional dependencies?

Thanks, JohnB